# keras lstm model in a bidirectional wrapper -- pass values to next layer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am working on this keras model. it is derived from nmt examples and is meant to be a chatbot. The specific question is about the Bidirectional wrapper around LSTM a. The bi wrapper returns 5 items. One is the return state and the other four are h_states and c_states, one set for the forward direction and one for backwards. Somehow I want to feed them to the next LSTM layer. I don't seem to be doing it effectively. To start with I don't know which is h, which is c and which two are forward and which two are back. The method I'm using to pass the values to the next lstm layer is not good. Can anyone help me out? I am using the tensorflow 1.6.0 backend and Keras 2.1.5 on a linux computer.

```
    def embedding_model_lstm( words,
                         embedding_weights_a=None,
                         trainable=False,
                         skip_embed=False,
                         return_sequences_b=False):

        lstm_unit_a = units
        lstm_unit_b = units # * 2
        embed_unit = 100 # int(hparams['embed_size'])

        x_shape = (tokens_per_sentence,)


        valid_word_a = Input(shape=x_shape)
        valid_word_b = Input(shape=x_shape)

        embeddings_a = Embedding(words,embed_unit ,
                                 weights=[embedding_weights_a],
                                 input_length=tokens_per_sentence,
                                 trainable=trainable
                                 )

        embed_a = embeddings_a(valid_word_a)

        ### encoder for training ###
        lstm_a = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=lstm_unit_a,
                                    return_sequences=True,
                                    return_state=True,
                                    #recurrent_dropout=0.2,
                                    input_shape=(None,),
                                    ), merge_mode='ave')

        recurrent_a, rec_a_1, rec_a_2, rec_a_3, rec_a_4 = lstm_a(embed_a) 

        concat_a_1 = Average()([rec_a_1, rec_a_3])
        concat_a_2 = Average()([rec_a_2, rec_a_4])

        lstm_a_states = [concat_a_1, concat_a_2]

        embed_b = embeddings_a(valid_word_b)

        lstm_b = LSTM(units=lstm_unit_b ,
                      #recurrent_dropout=0.2,
                      return_sequences=return_sequences_b,
                      return_state=True
                      )

        recurrent_b, inner_lstmb_h, inner_lstmb_c  = lstm_b(embed_b, initial_state=lstm_a_states)

        dense_b = Dense(embed_unit, input_shape=(tokens_per_sentence,),
                        activation='relu', #softmax or relu
                        )

        decoder_b = dense_b(recurrent_b) 

        model = Model([valid_word_a,valid_word_b], decoder_b) 

        ### encoder for inference ###
        model_encoder = Model(valid_word_a, lstm_a_states)

        ### decoder for inference ###
        input_h = Input(shape=(None, ))
        input_c = Input(shape=(None, ))

        inputs_inference = [input_h, input_c]


        embed_b = embeddings_a(valid_word_b)
        outputs_inference, outputs_inference_h, outputs_inference_c = lstm_b(embed_b,
                                                                             initial_state=inputs_inference)

        outputs_states = [outputs_inference_h, outputs_inference_c]

        dense_outputs_inference = dense_b(outputs_inference)

        ### inference model ###
        model_inference = Model([valid_word_b] + inputs_inference,
                                [dense_outputs_inference] +
                                outputs_states)

        return model, model_encoder, model_inference
```

I am using python3.

Comment: The order is `forward_h`, `forward_c`, `backward_h`, `backward_c`, so you're merging the states correctly. What do you mean by "not good" and "don't seem to be doing it effectively"? Do you see an error?

Comment: Have you tried `Concatenate` instead of `Average`?

Comment: when I try concatenate I have to double the size of lstm_b. Also I don't know which to put first, forward or backward. Do you think that's ok to double lstm_b? If I autoencode I get some small output, like one or two words and then the end-of-line symbol. Regular training on different x and y shows junk at the output. sometimes no pattern at all. It makes me think that the encoder(a) is not connected to the decoder(b) right. There is no error.

Comment: I think it's okay to double the number of units of lstm_b. The order shouldn't matter when concateneting the states.

Comment: btw: thanks. should I be using relu, or softmax for my dense layer? should I add a TimeDistributed to the dense function, or maybe TimeDistributed somewhere else?

Comment: Ah I didn't notice the output layer. If you're generating words, I think it should be `Dense(words, activation='softmax')`. `TimeDistributed` is not necessary here.